# Is this circuit ok for MCP9700 temp sensor?

Tags: temperature, surface-mount, attiny85

I am trying to use multiple MCP9700 temperature sensors and probe certain power IC heatsinks for sensing the temperature through an attiny85.

I have two parts in the overall schematic. For each MCP9700 temperature sensor I am having a circuit similar to this inside the control board where the attiny85 and 3.3V power source is located.
[image: the schematic on control board]

And then I am using 3 small distance wire for about 17cm each (max) to the physical MCP9700 temp sensor which is attached to the power mosfet heatsink for ground, vcc and signal. And also I am including a 1uF capacitor close to the temp sensor on its vcc and gnd pins and one 10R resistor close to the temp sensor signal pin which then connects to the board TS5 pin through the signal wire. And then the TS5 on board goes to attiny85 analogread pin for reading the temperature.

Is this a good application circuit design for the MCP9700 and attiny85 measurement? Should I adjust any resistor and capacitor values to get more stable and accurate temperature readings? Not really sure if my circuit is ok, so, would appreciate any tips and suggestion on this.

Comment: That depends on your ambient noise: Conducted ripple Vdd, radiated ,   ATtiny dC/dt from ADC sample

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I did not understand any of the things you just said. I am a total beginner in electronics design. Please guide me through with the terms.